# Get Volume Label From Drive Number (Not Drive Letter)

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi

I am able to get the volume label (what I want) from drive letters like this..

```
 try
        {
            DriveInfo[] myDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo drive in myDrives)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drive:" + drive.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Drive Type:" + drive.DriveType);

            if (drive.IsReady == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vol Label:" + drive.VolumeLabel);

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
```

but I want the volume label from a drive Number. I can get the drive numbers with this...

```
 foreach (var drive in new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList())
            {

                var driveNumber = Regex.Match((string)drive["Antecedent"], @"Disk #(\d*),").Groups[1].Value;

                Console.WriteLine("Drive Number: " + driveNumber);
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

How can I put something together to grab the volume label of all the given the drive numbers (from the 2nd code block shown)?

More Info:
I cannot use "LogicalDisk..." to query because I am finding mounted vhds which do not seem to be considered "logicalDisks

[image]

Comment: IMHO you are looking for the `Label` property of `Win32_Volume` class. Unfortunately, I can't see any association to the `Win32_DiskPartition` class.

Answer (score 1):

Follow up your search against `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition` with a search against `Win32_LogicalDisk` filtering by the ascertained driveLetter pulling back the `VolumeName` property.

```
            var drives = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>();
            var disks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk").Get().Cast<ManagementObject>();
            foreach (var drive in drives)
            {
                var driveLetter = Regex.Match((string)drive["Dependent"], @"DeviceID=""(.*)""").Groups[1].Value;
                var driveNumber = Regex.Match((string)drive["Antecedent"], @"Disk #(\d*),").Groups[1].Value;

                Console.WriteLine("Drive Letter: " + driveLetter);
                Console.WriteLine("Drive Number: " + driveNumber);

                // TODO: Enhance this to properly handle when the LINQ returns nothing.
                //       Likely only an edge case, but BSTS.
                var foundDisk = disks.Where((d) => d["Name"].ToString() == driveLetter).FirstOrDefault();

                // In the event that Drive Letter is not available, try the disk path
                if (foundDisk == null) {
                  foundDisk = disks.Where((d) => d.Path.ToString() == drive["Dependent"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                if (foundDisk == null) {
                  Console.WriteLine("Drive Label: <Unknown>");
                } else {
                  Console.WriteLine("Drive Label: " + foundDisk["VolumeName"]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Comment: The disks im querying don't have a drive letter just a drive number

Comment: @nlstack01 - okay - the above uses the `Path` that is stored in the `Dependent` property of the LogicalDiskToPartition. Does that work?

Comment: didnt work. I dont think I can use LogicalDiskwhatever because I have mounted vhds and those aren't considered logical disks

Comment: Does your mounted VHD have a volume name?

Comment: https://www.itprotoday.com/server-virtualization/q-what-my-vhd-files-drive-letter - has some references for Powershell commands to get the associated LogicalDisk. May help direct you.

Comment: I tried the code in the link but it doesn't seem to output anything. Looks promising can you post a version that will output info?

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "drive number" is named "Disk Index" in WMI parlance. You shouldn't have to parse anything to establish relations between WMI classes.

You can only get a volume label from a [Win32_LogicalDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk)'s `VolumeName` property. It should work for mounted VHD(X) as well. The following code browses all partitions (note a disk can have multiple partitions) and dumps the associated logical disks (note a partition can have multiple logical disks) volume names, if any:

```
foreach (var partition in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition").Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caption : " + partition["Caption"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Disk Index : " + partition["DiskIndex"]);

    // associate the partition with logical disk(s)
    foreach (var logicalDisk in new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" +
        partition["DeviceID"] +
        "'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition").Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" " + logicalDisk["VolumeName"]);
    }
}
```

If you want partitions and volume names for a given disk, just restrict the initial query, like this: `SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition WHERE DiskIndex=1` for example.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question. What I expect to get is the label "System Reserved"

Comment: You can try to run `SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume` and see if you get something in the `Label` property but my guess is you're looking at a System Reserved *partition*, that has no logical disk (nor volume since it's quite the same). The 'System Reserved' text is shown by the UI, it's not a label nor a name.